# Resize UITextView inside a UITableViewCell with iOS Autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, constraints, autolayout

### My Goal

I'm creating a custom UITableViewCell (MessageCell), and I'd wish to have my UITextView resizing both in width and height whenever the cell changes its size, while keeping some basic constraint like margins to the edges.

*Note : I also change my cell's height in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method depending on the content which will be placed into UITextView.*

### What I tried

Here are all the constraints currently applied & the cell :
[image]

I tried :

- With a `UILabel`.
- To fix a `Vertical Space` from the bottom, thinking it would change the height to fit all the constraints.
- To override `Height` with an User Constraint `Height >= 43` (my initial height), but the purple-automatic `Height` is re-created again whenever I do this.
- To find a solution on SO first, but didn't find a case like (even if the UITextView's height's resize with autolayout seems to be a frequent issue).
- Plenty of combinations of various & random constraints until my fingers bleds.

### How it render now

[image]

### So...

If someone has any clue or guideline to achieve my goal, I'd appreciate!

*I might add, I'm totally new to Autolayout & constraints. My reference : [Ray Wenderlich's awesomeness](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of that height constraint that the text view has. Make sure you have constraints to something above and below the text view (usually the top and bottom of the cell), and then you should be able to delete that height constraint.

Comment: Ok, I get it, XCode had no other information on how big should the UITextView be, so it generated the height each time. Weirdly, I think I already tried your way, but I must have missed it. Thanks!

Comment: Just to say that this little bit of info solved a problem I had spent the last 4 hours going around in circles with. Awesome! I really like Autolayout but it can cause some very tricky problems until you get the hang of it!

Comment: how do you handle the UITableCell custom row height? 
if set, the text will adapt to the height specified. so the view will always be the custom row height not the size needed for textview?